# How to get parent view oData model in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I have a master-details application in SAPUI5 (The application has been made by WebIde template applications). 
The view inside of the `App` is set to busy and I need to unbusy the view in child view. Thus I need to access the parent view.

So in `Master.controller.js` I need to access the owner component view. All controllers inherited from BasicController and have `setModel` and `getModel` functions. While inside of the `App.controller.js` there is a line like this:

```
this.setModel(oViewModel, "appView");
```

I can not access this view model in master controller by:

```
this.getModel("appView");
```

It returns `undefined`. There is command that I can get owner component:

```
this.getOwnerComponent()
```

But how can I get view of the owner component or its `OViewModel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See your rootView in your manifest.json which should be your App controller.   https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da.html

Put the following code in your base controller.

```
this.getOwnerComponent().getAggregation("rootControl").getModel("appView")
```

I tried the code in **Worklist.controller.js** which is part of a UI5 demo project at https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/tutorial/worklist/07/webapp/test/mockServer.html and it is working OK.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You want to access a model that is defined only in DetailView from the  Masterview controller?

First get a grip on the DetailView, then you can access the model there.

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("IdOfDetailView").getModel("appView");
```

Comment: Where do I have to define the `IdOfDetailView`?? Inside of the Deatil.view.XML in `<mvc:View>` tag? Or it is the id that has been used inside of the Detail.controller.js that create a JSON model for that.

Comment: If you used the template the id is defined in the "targets" section of manifest.json 

    ...
    "object": {
     "viewName": "Detail",
     "viewId": "xyz",
     "viewLevel": 2
    },
    ...

But the ids inherit parts of their context so my id looks like "application-masterDetail-display-component---xyz"

If you use chrome, you can open the developer tools (F12) and search for e.g "xyz" in the "Elements" tab. There you will see your full id.

Comment: The problem is that the model has been defined inside of the App.Controller.js and the App view is not part of the taget views. It is the root view.

Comment: Same procedure for the appView
its id is defined in manifest.json "rootView"
search for this view and acess the model

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access your models anywhere as long as you used `getModel()` with the correct name inside the parenthesis. Do you have a model defined in your `Component.js`, or wherever SAP suggests defining them, named "appView"?

Comment: Yes. It defines inside of the App.controller.js. I used the templates project of SAP Web IDE.